# XPath 2 / XSLT : Find sibling nodes of a set with matching values of child node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath-2.0

I couldn't find this question in particular answered anywhere, and I've been struggling with it. I'd like to be able to select with XPath all nodes in the set with a child node value A for which exists another node in the set with the same child node value A, and pair them together.

For example, I have an XML document which lists movies, 'imdb'. The nodes here follow the pattern:

```
<movie>
  <title>Pirates of the Carribbean: At World's End</title>
  <year>2007</year>
  <directors>
    <director>Gore Verbinski</director>
  </directors>
  <actors>
    <actor>Johnny Depp</actor>
     ......
    </actors>
</movie>
```

In this example I'd like to find all movies which feature Johnny Depp that have come out in the same year as another movie of the same. In my output I'm sorting this by years - so, for every year which has more than two movies with Johnny Depp, I want to output that year along with those movies.

My XSLT for-each select so far looks like this:
`<xsl:for-each select="/imdb/movie[contains(actors/actor/text(), 'Johnny Depp')][year = following-sibling::movie/year]">`

But that seems to just output every movie Johnny Depp has been in. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for every year which has more than two movies with Johnny Depp, I want to output that year along with those movies.

That's

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="movie" group-by="year">
  <xsl:variable name="depp-movies" 
                select="current-group()[actors/actor='johnny depp']"/>
  <xsl:if test="count($depp-movies) gt 2">
    <year year="{current-grouping-key()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
    </
  </
</
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. Between posting the question and your answer I'd discovered the 'for-each-group' function but was having difficulty getting it to work properly. Your example works well except it ends up outputting all movies because of the 'copy-of select="current-group()"'. I modified the output with a for-each to select only specific bits of information and sorted the outputs by year, and it all works.

Answer (score 1):

Your current query returns every movie which satisfies the two predicates

1. The `movie` element contains an `actor` element whose string value includes 'Johnny Depp'.
2. The `movie` element has a following sibling element with the same year.

That is, it matches every Johnny Depp movie which is not the last movie in the document made in the given year.  The `following-sibling` axis is going to identify the siblings of the given `movie` element in the input, not the other `movie` elements in a sorted list.

You should read up on `xsl:for-each-group`.